# How to check if I have a charm or cursed table?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

Is there any way to check weather my character has a charm table or a cursed one? Also, if there is a list of all the charms and curses, could someone leave link a link to it?

Comment: I just want to add that "how do I check which table and what affect I have?" and "what are curse tables?" is NOT the same thing.

Comment: I concur.  This should not have been closed.  I have voted to reopen.

Comment: The duplicate question covers this as well, and the accepted answer includes instructions for checking your charm table. It is a duplicate.